# How to run multiple synchronous functions in parallel – like Promise.all/allSettled

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given I have a synchronous function like:

```
const append = (input: string): string => input + ' hi';
```

If `append()` returned a promise, I could do something like:

```
const result = await Promise.all(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].map(async x => append(x)));
```

I understand JS is not multithreaded but is there a benefit to trying to execute `append()` in parallel and how should I do that? This would not make sense, right?

```
const result = await Promise.all(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].map(x => append(x)));
```

Comment: It won't execute in paralell

Comment: The promisified version also isn't parallel, there is no parallel processing in JS (except with workers in Node, which wouldn't be useful for a problem like this). There is no benefit here.

Comment: js offers concurrency, not parallelism https://freecontent.manning.com/concurrency-vs-parallelism/#:~:text=Concurrency%20is%20about%20multiple%20tasks,resources%20like%20multi%2Dcore%20processor.

Comment: "*This would not make sense, right?*" - right.